# IPsec: Can ping hosts of other network with the firewall but not with hosts behind the firewall

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, ping, endian-firewall

I have a endian firewall and a established IPsec tunnel. The firewall is in the network `192.168.100.0/24` and has the address `192.168.100.1`. The hosts that I try to ping are in the network `10.4.0.0/32` and the specific addresses are `10.4.0.198` and `10.4.0.199`. Between the network `192.168.100.0/24` and `10.4.0.0/32` is that IPsec tunnel. The ping from the firewall itself to the host `10.4.0.198` works, but if I try to ping these hosts with a windows pc behind the firewall it doesn't work. Any suggestion what could be the problem? I already added the rule `iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -d 10.4.0.0/32 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT` but it still doesn't work. The iptables are huge so it wouldn't be of advantage if i post every code. But here is the output from `route`:

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

defaultHSI-KBW-46-237- 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1

1.1.1.0         *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2

10.31.1.0       vpn.svsnls.neug 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 br0

10.255.255.0    vpn.admedespfor 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 br0

46.237.253.64   *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth1

192.168.4.0     vpn.jurabadgosh 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 br0

192.168.8.0     vpn.grundschule 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 br0

...

Answer (score 0):

10.4.0.0/32 it's a single host and not a subnet, this is why is not working, you should modify the subnet with the right network mask

```
daniele@bart:~$ sipcalc 10.4.0.0/32
-[ipv4 : 10.4.0.0/32] - 0

[CIDR]
Host address        - 10.4.0.0
Host address (decimal)  - 168034304
Host address (hex)  - A040000
Network address     - 10.4.0.0
Network mask        - 255.255.255.255
Network mask (bits) - 32
Network mask (hex)  - FFFFFFFF
Broadcast address   - 10.4.0.0
Cisco wildcard      - 0.0.0.0
Addresses in network    - 1
Network range       - 10.4.0.0 - 10.4.0.0
```